# How can you get the location for a specified place using google map flutter?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, google-maps-flutter

I was trying to access the **LatLng** for a chosen place that is not at my location. How can you do that in flutter with the google_maps_flutter plugin? and why is it restricted to Android lolipop and above.

Comment: You need to use external API for the address to the lat-long convertor. Try this package https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder

Comment: Great! Feel free to upvote comment.